# ListView in HorizontalScrollView - getView() called too many times after setSelection()

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

Hello everyone and thank you for your time. I hope, someone will be able to help with my problem. I'm stucked.

**Goal:**
I'm trying to make a layout with two ListViews, that scroll together (code below) - if user scrolls first ListView, second is scrolled too, if user scrolls second ListView, first is scrolld too. With their synchronization is no problem. Here is code of syncer, which I use.

```
class ListScrollSyncer implements OnScrollListener, OnTouchListener {

    private Set<ListView> listSet = new HashSet<ListView>();
    private ListView currentTouchSource;

    private int currentOffset = 0;
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    public void addList(ListView list) {
        listSet.add(list);
        list.setOnTouchListener(this);
        list.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition, currentOffset);
    }

    public void removeList(ListView list) {
        listSet.remove(list);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        ListView list = (ListView) view;

        if (currentTouchSource != null) {
            currentTouchSource.setOnScrollListener(null);
        }
        currentTouchSource = list;
        currentTouchSource.setOnScrollListener(this);


        return false;
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        scrollToPosition();
    }

    private void scrollToPosition() {
        if (currentTouchSource.getChildCount() > 0) {
            currentPosition = currentTouchSource.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            currentOffset   = currentTouchSource.getChildAt(0).getTop();
        }
        Iterator<ListView> it = listSet.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ListView list = it.next();
            if (list == currentTouchSource) {
                continue;
            }
            list.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition, currentOffset);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && currentTouchSource != null) {
            scrollToPosition();
            currentTouchSource.setOnScrollListener(null);
            currentTouchSource = null;
        }
    }   
}
```

**Problem:**
One of ListView is inside an HorizontalScrollView. Both direction works fine, but when I call method setSelection() or setSelectionFromTop() for this ListView, getView() with position 0 is called after every setSelection*() method, which causes real performance issue.

**Question:** How to avoid repeatading measure of ListView inside a HorizontalScrollView, after setSelection*() is called?

**What I found out**

- If ListView is placed in FrameLayout, everything works fine. Problem is only if it's in HorizontalScrollView. I thought, reuqestLayout() could be problem, so I took HorizontalScrollView and used parent's requestLayout() - parent of HorizontalScrollView is FrameLayout, but this also didn't work and I have no more ideas, where could be problem.
- I know, or at least I presume, there is a problem with requesting size of ListView from HorizontalScrollView after requestLayout, but I don't know.
- wrap_content/match_parent/fixed_size_in_dp set for layout_width and layout_height has no effect.

Thanks for your time and help.

**update 1** added layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <!-- First cell -->
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/first_cell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/first_col_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_cell"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/header_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_cell"
    />


    <!-- Header -->
    <com.peterbucko.android.example.fixedheaderstable.SyncedHorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/header_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_col_divider"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

    </com.peterbucko.android.example.fixedheaderstable.SyncedHorizontalScrollView>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/first_col"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_divider"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/first_cell"
    />


    <com.peterbucko.android.example.fixedheaderstable.SyncedHorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_divider"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_col_divider"
        android:fillViewport="true"
    >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       />


    </com.peterbucko.android.example.fixedheaderstable.SyncedHorizontalScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

note: SyncedHorizontalScrollView is HorizontalScrollView with listener for scrolling, so I can synchronize horizontal scrolling of two HorizontalScrollView.

**update 2** I tried create a minimalistic project with this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"    
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF00ff00"    
    />    

</LinearLayout>
```

With this layout, there is problem with both ListView - both are remeasured after setSelection*(). But with layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:background="#FF00ff00"    
    />    

</FrameLayout>
```

there is no problem and getView is called when it's needed - when new item should be shown.

I can imagine, there is some mechanism for remeasuring whole layout different for every Layout View. So here is a question. How should an layout look like and which Views should use for result I need? Probably I could make a custom FrameLayout, which would act like HorizontalScrollView, but HorizontalScrollView is already descendant of FrameLayout.

Comment: post your layout because I need to check something on it, may be I can help.